# How to plot a contour of a specific layer output from CNN?

Tags: matplotlib, keras, conv-neural-network, data-visualization

I am trying to pick up an output from a specific layer in CNN and visualize it with matplotlib.pyplot.contour. This is my CNN architecture

```
input_img = Input(shape=(384, 192, 2))
## Encoder
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='tanh', padding='same')(input_img)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='tanh', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='tanh', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='tanh', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='tanh', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='tanh', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Reshape([6*3*4])(x)
encoded = Dense(2,activation='tanh')(x)
## Two variables
val1= Lambda(lambda x: x[:,0:1])(encoded)
val2= Lambda(lambda x: x[:,1:2])(encoded)
## Decoder 1
x1 = Dense(6*3*4,activation='tanh')(val1)
x1 = Reshape([6,3,4])(x1)
x1 = UpSampling2D((2,2))(x1)
x1 = Conv2D(4,(3,3),activation='tanh',padding='same')(x1)
x1 = UpSampling2D((2,2))(x1)
x1 = Conv2D(8,(3,3),activation='tanh',padding='same')(x1)
x1 = UpSampling2D((2,2))(x1)
x1 = Conv2D(8,(3,3),activation='tanh',padding='same')(x1)
x1 = UpSampling2D((2,2))(x1)
x1 = Conv2D(8,(3,3),activation='tanh',padding='same')(x1)
x1 = UpSampling2D((2,2))(x1)
x1 = Conv2D(16,(3,3),activation='tanh',padding='same')(x1)
x1 = UpSampling2D((2,2))(x1)
x1d = Conv2D(2,(3,3),activation='linear',padding='same')(x1)
## Decoder 2
x2 = Dense(6*3*4,activation='tanh')(val2)
x2 = Reshape([6,3,4])(x2)
x2 = UpSampling2D((2,2))(x2)
x2 = Conv2D(4,(3,3),activation='tanh',padding='same')(x2)
x2 = UpSampling2D((2,2))(x2)
x2 = Conv2D(8,(3,3),activation='tanh',padding='same')(x2)
x2 = UpSampling2D((2,2))(x2)
x2 = Conv2D(8,(3,3),activation='tanh',padding='same')(x2)
x2 = UpSampling2D((2,2))(x2)
x2 = Conv2D(8,(3,3),activation='tanh',padding='same')(x2)
x2 = UpSampling2D((2,2))(x2)
x2 = Conv2D(16,(3,3),activation='tanh',padding='same')(x2)
x2 = UpSampling2D((2,2))(x2)
x2d = Conv2D(2,(3,3),activation='linear',padding='same')(x2)

decoded = Add()([x1d,x2d])

autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

# Check the network structure
autoencoder.summary()
```

I got the output of x1d layer as the code below with the output shape TensorShape([None, 72])

```
r1 = autoencoder.layers[13].output
r1.shape
```

How do I visualize this r1 output with matplotlib contour, the output should be like this photo.
[image]

I appriciate any help or suggestion. Thank you very much!

Comment: is there any help?

Comment: I have solve this by using plt.pcolormesh(X_train[0][:,:,0].T, cmap = cm.jet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pcolormesh works for me.

> plt.pcolormesh(X_train[0][:,:,0].T, cmap = cm.jet)